# Separating a String in AS3

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

If I have a string, for example "Tiger," what could I write that would return T + i + g + e + r? It would be nice if I could put each letter inside of an array.

I need this because I'm writing a program that analyzes an inputted string and determines how many times repeated letters occur.

Comment: I'd suggest you iterate over the string with `.length` as a maximum and `.charAt(i)` or `charCodeAt(i)` for character fetching and then increment an array position based on what letter it was. No need for anything more fancy than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [**String.split()**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29) method with empty delimeter:

```
var str:String = "Tiger";
var letters:Array = str.split('');
//result->  ["T","i","g","e","r"]
```